# pgAdmin on postgres importing csv files to table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am having issues importing csv/text files on pgAdmin postgres. I have worked with postgres 9 and 10 and I hadn't had any issues with importing until I upgraded to 12.I never seen a Failed (exit code: -6). Do any of y'all know what it means and how I can fix it ?  I don't know if it is a Mac issue.

**error code**

[image]

Comment: are there any comma at unexpected place? if the data you are uploading is provide a link to the database.

Comment: https://github.com/jiayuasu/Coursera-ASU-Database/tree/master/course1/assignment1/exampleinput  ~so I got rid of the quotes replace the % to , and it doesn't work

Comment: whats the schema of table in which u r pushing data?

Comment: in this picture, it is genresid and name. I am saving the CSV files on my Desktop

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of the EDB installer. I uninstall that distribution and after that, I installed [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) and then the [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) and everything works fine. I hope that helps.